# Am I asked to express my opinion?

Tags: writing, ielts, academic-writing

In IELTS band descriptor, it is clearly written that I have to mention a position and stick to it throughout the essay from Introduction to Conclusion.

> Band 9: “presents a fully developed position“
> Band 7: “presents a clear position throughout the response”
> Band 6: “presents a relevant position“

However, there are certain task 2 questions that are clearly not asking for any opinion.

Such as,

> It is commonly believed that nowadays main factors that affect a child's development are media, pop culture and friends. A different point of view is that family plays the most significant role.
> Discuss both views.

If I can't mention an opinion, how can I make my position clear?

Comment: Most such essays require a relevant position - clear (say it), consistent (keep going), and developed (supported by something other than *I think so*). You can also insert an opposing opinion and explain why you disagree. The childhood essay **gives you** two positions to take - I'd compare and contrast. No contradictions there.

Comment: Who says that you 'can't mention an opinion'? Asking somebody to discuss something implies a request for an opinion about it (a thought-out, argued-for opinion, that is).

Comment: Even though IELTS is a test of English skills, the actual question being asked ("how can I make my position clear?") could apply to any language. I therefore don't think that this is appropriate for ELU; because it asks about writing an essay, perhaps Writing SE would be better.

Comment: The expressions "**it is believed**" and "**a point of view**" are two ways of saying "(in my) in someone's opinion". They are **not talking about facts**,  but in your essay  you must mention BOTH SIDES of the argument. This type of essay is normally called a ["balanced" or "a for and against" essay](https://www.cristinacabal.com/?p=7367)

Comment: @Mari-LouA, yes, asking somebody to discuss the issue, implies that one has to explore both sides of it (or however many sides there are), but it doesn't preclude reaching, as a result of the discussion, the conclusion that one side is more convincing than the other.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan, on the other side, the question could be interpreted as a question about some aspects of the meaning of the word *discuss* in English (which may or may not be shared by similar words in other languages.)

Comment: @jsw29 on an IELTS writing test, time is short, and candidates are asked to write a 250 word long essay. If the candidates talk about their opinion they could be penalised because this type of essay writing is about  illustrating the pros and cons, the fors and againsts, the benefits and disadvantages etc. A candidate could sum up the arguments and then give their personal opinion. I don't think an examiner would downmark an essay if that happened.

Comment: This appears to be a question about the IELTS exam and understanding how "Discuss both views" can be reconciled to "presents a relevant, clear, fully-developed position throughout the response". Those requirements are not mutually-exclusive, in my opinion; but the question is better suited to ELL, simply because IELTS is designed for non-native English language speakers.

Comment: "I think media is important, because.... I think parents are unimportant, because...." There you go. Two opposing views discussed with your opinion presented. This is madly off topic and no idea why it's not closed, but I guess it's too old now.

Answer (score 0):

Interpretation of these guidelines and how to apply them is really down to those who set them. In other words, you should ask your tutors what it means rather than strangers on the internet, as you may get differing opinions. I'd say your grades are quite important, so make sure you get the right answer from the right people.

However, it is a fact that a neutral position is still a position. In an essay where you are presenting both a mainstream view held by others alongside an alternative view, you could adopt an unbiased position and simply report the views of both sides. You can even point out pros or cons, so long as the analysis you use is fair to both sides.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest it depends on the type of the essay you are required to write. In some essays, you lose mark when you express your opinion all over the essay. Rather than explaining by myself which I can perfectly do; I prefer to direct you [to the Liz's website](https://ieltsliz.com/ielts-discussion-essay-model-answer/) to read a band 9 discussion essay as I learned from her. In a discussion essay, **you can perfectly express your opinion in the final paragraph or last body paragraph, after you discussed different views.**

It's beneficial to mention that IELTS has its own guidelines (and convention) which are not very strick, luckily. Therefore, suggestions coming from experts such as ESL teachers who don't have teaching IELTS experience might be misleading.

Also: [when to give your opinion](https://ieltsliz.com/ielts-writing-task-2-should-i-give-my-opinion/)

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Preface: I have helped Italian students earn a 6.5, 7.0 and 8.0 for the IELTS writing paper, so I actually have some  hands-on experience.</sub>

The expressions “**it is believed**” and “**a point of view**” are two ways of saying "in [someone's]opinion". These do not express [cold, hard facts](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cold+hard+facts), and in this case the exam question clearly demands: ***‘Discuss both views’***. Therefore, an IELTS exam candidate *must* mention BOTH SIDES of the argument.

This type of essay is normally called a "[balanced](https://alexwallselt.com/2021/11/03/ielts-writing-balanced-opinion-essay-2/)" or "[a for and against essay](https://learnenglishteens.britishcouncil.org/skills/writing/b1-writing/against-essay)". The candidate is not asked to what extent they agree or disagree with a statement but  nothing impedes a candidate to choose a side, as long as the for and against arguments have been satisfactorily dealt with.